# Python File IO failure with specific extension "html"

Tags: python

I had very weird issue using Python (I am very new to Python). I can write to a file successfully, however would be failed if the filename has extension ".html".

Screen shot below is the error, I am very sure the same name file doesn't exist. If I change ".html" to ".tml", then the code would be working. My OS is windows 8. Python version is 2.7.9

[Error Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILcLi.png)

All people spends time would be very appreciated.

Comment: Try open the file in 'r+' mode instead of 'w'. Does it work?

Comment: Hi Fabio, it works if using 'r+'.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
with open('abc.html', 'r+') as f:
    f.write('abc')
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says `Permission denied`. Make sure you have permission to write to the file.

Comment: I do have permission, otherwise I neither can write to ".tml"

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is unknown and but today I turned on the PC again and run the script and it works. It shames it just worked after PC restarted.

Thanks, Fabio and DhaLee